# Python - Decorator error

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am new to python and I am now learning **decorators**. Here is the python decorator example I'm working on:

```
def makeHtmlTag(tag, *args, **kwds):
    def real_decorator(fn):
        css_class = " class='{0}'".format(kwds["css_class"]) \
                                     if "css_class" in kwds else ""

        def wrapped():
            return "<"+tag+css_class+">" + fn() + "</"+tag+">"
        return wrapped
    return real_decorator

@makeHtmlTag(tag="i", css_class="italic_css")
def hello():
    return "hello world"

print hello()
```

When I replace function `wrapped()` with only one line as follows:

```
return "<"+tag+css_class+">" + fn() + "</"+tag+">"
```

I get `TypeError`. Why is that?

Comment: Real decorator needs to return a function, not a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A decorator replaces the function object; the syntax is essentially executed as:

```
def hello():
    return "hello world"
hello = makeHtmlTag(tag="i", css_class="italic_css")(hello)
```

`makeHtmlTag()` returns the `real_decorator()` function, which is called with `hello` as the argument, and it in turn returns `wrapped()`.

So, after the decorator has been called, `hello` is now bound to the `wrapped()` function the `real_decorator()` nested function returned.

If you *replace* `def wrapped()` .. `return wrapped` with a `return` statement returning just a string, then `hello` is now bound to that string and is not a function anymore. You cannot call a string object, leading to your `TypeError` exception.